# Python и OpenOPC

Tags: python, opc

Может кто-то подсказать ну или попробовать у себя следующее:

1. Установил модули *pypiwin32* (нужен *win32com.client*) и *Pyro*
2. Скачал модуль *OpenOPC* (ссылка на модуль https://sourceforge.net/projects/openopc/files/  )
3. Пишу `import OpenOPC`
4. Далее пишу `opc = OpenOPC.client()` и получаю следующую ошибку:

> Traceback (most recent call last): 
>   File "", line 1, in 
>   opc = OpenOPC.client()
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\OpenOPC.py", line 176, in **init**
>   raise OPCError, error_msg
>   OPCError: Dispatch: Недопустимая строка с указанием класса

Опыта немного, может кто что подскажет, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй установить любой OPC server, подойдет симулятор. В моем случае установка Lectus OPC в качестве симулятора OPC для проекта решил данную проблему